# How to write SQL Like which returns the zeros before character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a column called `SeialNumber` which sometimes by mistake starts with different number of zeros.

I want to find out the `SerialNumber` that start with any number of 0 before reaching a character and save the zeros in a variable called `prefix`.  I have the following code. However, I think there should be smarter way of writing it. Is there anyway (for example with regular expressions) to write the `SQL` with less `If Else`, for example a smarter `like` or `regEx`:

```
declare @prefix [nvarchar](10) = '##@#*#^#!' -- initial value
        if @SerialNumber like '000000%'
            set @prefix = '000000'
        else if @SerialNumber like '00000%'
            set @prefix = '00000'
        else if @SerialNumber like '0000%'
            set @prefix = '0000'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `patindex()` to find the first non-0.  Then you can use `replicate()` to create the string:

```
set @prefix = replicate('0', patindex('%[^0]%', @SerialNumber + 'X')  - 1)
```

Or, you can use `left()`:

```
set @prefix = left(@SerialNumber, patindex('%[^0]%', @SerialNumber + 'X')  - 1)
```

Comment: Sorry but why we have concat '0' with @serailNumber ?

Comment: @BhatiaAshish . . . That was a mistake.  The intention is to prevent a problem if the serial number is all 0s.  I changed that to "X".

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I meant the store procedure that I have this line of SQL there. I was thinking about the performance difference of using LIKE vs using the PATINDEX . I will figure it out by testing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `left()` function without the use of `replicate()` function

```
set @prefix = left(@SerialNumber , patindex('%[1-9]%', @SerialNumber )-1)
```

However, you could put additional `case` expression or condition in case of the serial_no has all `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `SUBSTRING` like this :

```
set @prefix = SUBSTRING(@SerialNumber, 1, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @SerialNumber) - 1)
```